# PHP - get var inside a function

Tags: php, variables, global-variables

I have a function which are inside a class, and i want a var from a function. I am using `$this` to call var from a function inside a class. but dont know how to call function with a parameter. I want `$post['who']['points']` to use outside function.

**function**

```
function post_meta_who($post, $class)
        {
            if (isset($post['who'])) {
                $this->output('<SPAN CLASS="'.$class.'-who">');

                if (strlen(@$post['who']['prefix']))
                    $this->output('<SPAN CLASS="'.$class.'-who-pad">'.$post['who']['prefix'].'</SPAN>');

                if (isset($post['who']['data']))
                    $this->output('<SPAN CLASS="'.$class.'-who-data">'.$post['who']['data'].'</SPAN>');

                if (isset($post['who']['title']))
                    $this->output('<SPAN CLASS="'.$class.'-who-title">'.$post['who']['title'].'</SPAN>');

                // You can also use $post['level'] to get the author's privilege level (as a string)

                if (isset($post['who']['points'])) {
                    $post['who']['points']['prefix']='('.$post['who']['points']['prefix'];
                    $post['who']['points']['suffix'].=')';
                    $this->output_split($post['who']['points'], $class.'-who-points');
                }

                if (strlen(@$post['who']['suffix']))
                    $this->output('<SPAN CLASS="'.$class.'-who-pad">'.$post['who']['suffix'].'</SPAN>');

                $this->output('</SPAN>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I still don´t understand your question.

If you want to use a variable in the function from outside you should declare it as global

```
global $variable;
```

If you want to get the return statement you just have to write

```
$result=post_meta_who("example","example");
```

Greets

Comment: there is not any return inside the function. I want to use `$post['who']['points']` outside function. I am inside a calass so i dont need to set global, only $this will work. right???

Comment: Yes. If you have the variable (or array) $post['who']['points'] in your class it should work with ` $this->post['who']['points'] `

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj->post['who']['points']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you need to pass in `$post` [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

To do this alter the function declaration to look like this:

```
function post_meta_who(&$post, $class) {
    ...
}
```

The ampersand (&) [passes in the variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) so any changes made to `$post` inside the method will have an effect on the variable outside of the method.

I hope this helps to answer your question.